# как определить через tcp-сокеты что окончена передача http запроса c keep-alive опцией

Tags: tcp, сокеты

здравствуйте, допустим, есть у меня серверный tcp-сокет, который принимает данные, например http-запросы. естествено, данные бьются на пакеты, и принимаются пакетами, и когда принимается 0 байт, то считается что клиент закрыл соединение... а как узнать что окончена передача http-запроса т.е. все пакеты переданы, но клиентский сокет не закрылся? например, при keep-alive соединении

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66636/discussion-on-question-by-xperious----tcp---).